# A singular average integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(\theta, \epsilon)$ be continuous on the unit circle for $\epsilon>0$, $f(\theta, \epsilon)>0$ for $\epsilon>0$, and $f(\theta, 0)=(\theta -\theta^*)^2h(\theta)$ with $h(\theta)>0$ for all $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. Is the following true?
$$\lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\big(\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin \theta}{f(\theta, \epsilon)}d\theta\big)\big(\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{f(\theta, \epsilon) } d \theta\big)^{-1}=\sin (\theta^*).$$

Intuitively, the limit should give us the weighted average, and if we have a singularity the average should be $\sin \theta^*$. I am not sure how to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider more generally the limit

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{F(\theta)}{f(\theta,\epsilon)}d\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{f(\theta,\epsilon)}d\theta}$$

where $F(\theta)$ is also continuous on the unit circle just like $\sin\theta$ is. WLOG continuity on the unit circle means we can integrate over any $2\pi$ period we wish and can translate $\theta^*$ to $0$ in the integrand, giving us the equivalent limit

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{F(\theta)}{f(\theta,\epsilon)}d\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{f(\theta,\epsilon)}d\theta} = \lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{F(\theta+\theta^*)}{g(\theta,\epsilon)}d\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{g(\theta,\epsilon)}d\theta}$$

where $g(\theta,\epsilon) = f(\theta+\theta^*,\epsilon)$. Now consider the substitution

$$q = \epsilon\frac{\int_0^{\theta}\frac{1}{g(\varphi,\epsilon)}d\varphi}{\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{g(\varphi,\epsilon)}d\varphi}$$

The factor of $\epsilon$ out front ensures that for the entire interval $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$ we have

$$|q| \leq \epsilon\left|\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{g(\varphi,\epsilon)}d\varphi}{\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{g(\varphi,\epsilon)}d\varphi}\right| =\epsilon$$

due to the condition that $g(\theta,\epsilon)>0$ for every $\epsilon>0$. Translating the limiting singularity to $0$ also allowed us to keep the integrand unsplit.

Under this substitution the limit becomes

$$ \lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{F(\theta+\theta^*)}{g(\theta,\epsilon)}d\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{g(\theta,\epsilon)}d\theta} = \lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^\epsilon F(\theta(q)+\theta^*)\:dq = F\Bigr(\theta(0)+\theta^*\Bigr) = F(\theta^*)$$

by dominated convergence.

Comment: @MathKid - Two things: (1) The zero cannot be of odd order because that would violate your condition that $f(\theta,\epsilon) > 0 $ for all $\epsilon > 0$. (2) I used the assumption of the singularity in the small statement I made about not having to split the integral up. Taking the FTC limit at the very end takes the derivative of the integral towards the point of the singularity, not towards the point $\theta=0$ in general. This would've been more obvious if I had two separate integrals over parts of the period of $2\pi$ split up at $\theta^*$, but this simplification is nicer.

Comment: I just posted a follow up question. I would appreciate if you could take a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4785142/rate-of-convergence-in-a-singular-average-integral