# Convergence in an average integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(\theta, \epsilon)$ be smooth on  $[0,2\pi] \times [0,\infty)$, $f(\theta, \epsilon)>0$ for $\epsilon>0$, and $f(\theta, 0)=(\theta -\theta^*)^2h(\theta)$ with $h(\theta)>0$ for all $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. It is shown in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749667/a-singular-average-integral) that, for $\theta^*\neq 0$, $\lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\theta(\epsilon)=\theta^*$, where
$$\theta(\epsilon):=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\theta }{f(\theta, \epsilon)}d\theta (\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{f(\theta, \epsilon)  d \theta})^{-1}.$$

Now let
$$\alpha(\epsilon):=f(\theta(\epsilon), \epsilon), \ \ and \ \  \beta(\epsilon) :=\min_{\theta \in [0,2\pi]}f(\theta, \epsilon).$$

Both $\alpha(\epsilon)$ and $\beta(\epsilon)$ converge to zero as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ with $\beta(\epsilon) \leq \alpha (\epsilon)$. For $\theta^* \neq 0$, does there exists a function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(0)=0$, and $g(s)>0$ for $s\neq 0$ such that
$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(\alpha (\epsilon))}{\beta(\epsilon)}=0?$$

Comment: I think I can prove that $\alpha(\epsilon)-\beta(\epsilon)$ is $O(\beta(\epsilon)^2)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. I'll try and write a proof within the next day or so.

Comment: @JulianNewman Thank you very much. When will you have the time to write up your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I realised that there was a mistake in my first solution, and the combination of obtaining a corrected solution together with all my other busyness has made it take a lot longer to respond. I'm going to try tonight, but no guarantees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proposition.** *$\alpha(\epsilon)-\beta(\epsilon)$ is $O(\beta(\epsilon)[\log(\beta(\epsilon))]^2)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.*

[Hence in particular, $\alpha(\epsilon)-\beta(\epsilon)$ is $o(\beta(\epsilon)^{1-\gamma})$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ for all $\gamma>0$.]

*Proof.* By assumption, $\partial_{\theta\theta}^2 f(\theta^\ast,0)$ is strictly positive and the point $\theta^\ast \in (0,2\pi)$ is the only zero of $f(\,\cdot\,,0)$ in $[0,2\pi)$. Hence, by the smoothness assumptions [see further details at the bottom]:

1. for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, there exists a unique $\theta^\ast(\epsilon) \in [0,2\pi)$ such that $f(\theta^\ast(\epsilon),\epsilon)=\beta(\epsilon)$;
2. there exist constants $c_-,c_+,\Delta>0$ such that for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$,

- $0 < \theta^\ast(\epsilon) - \Delta < \theta^\ast(\epsilon) + \Delta < 2\pi$;
- for every $\theta \in \big[\theta^\ast(\epsilon) - \Delta,\theta^\ast(\epsilon) + \Delta\big]$,
  $$ \beta(\epsilon) + c_-(\theta-\theta^\ast(\epsilon))^2 \leq f(\theta,\epsilon) \leq \beta(\epsilon) + c_+(\theta-\theta^\ast(\epsilon))^2 \, ; $$
- for every $\theta \in [0,2\pi) \setminus \big[\theta^\ast(\epsilon) - \Delta,\theta^\ast(\epsilon) + \Delta\big]$,
  $$ f(\theta,\epsilon) > \beta(\epsilon) + c_-\Delta^2. $$

Now for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$,
$$ |\theta(\epsilon) - \theta^\ast(\epsilon)| = \left| \frac{ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\theta-\theta^\ast(\epsilon)}{f(\theta,\epsilon)} \, d\theta }{ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{f(\theta,\epsilon)} \, d\theta } \right| \leq \frac{A(\epsilon) + B(\epsilon)}{C(\epsilon)} $$
with
\begin{align*}
A(\epsilon) = \int_{\theta^\ast(\epsilon)-\Delta}^{\theta^\ast(\epsilon)+\Delta} \frac{|\theta-\theta^\ast(\epsilon)|}{f(\theta,\epsilon)} \, d\theta & \\ & \\
B(\epsilon) = \int_{[0,2\pi] \ \setminus \ [\theta^\ast(\epsilon)-\Delta \ , \ \theta^\ast(\epsilon)+\Delta]} \frac{|\theta-\theta^\ast(\epsilon)|}{f(\theta,\epsilon)} \, d\theta & \\ & \\
C(\epsilon) = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{f(\theta,\epsilon)} \, d\theta & \, .
\end{align*}
For sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$,
\begin{align*}
A(\epsilon) &\leq \int_{\theta^\ast(\epsilon) - \Delta}^{\theta^\ast(\epsilon) + \Delta} \frac{|\theta-\theta^\ast(\epsilon)|}{\beta(\epsilon) + c_-(\theta-\theta^\ast(\epsilon))^2} \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{c_-} \log\!\left( 1 + \frac{c_-\Delta^2}{\beta(\epsilon)} \right) \\
&\leq -k_A\log\!\left( \beta(\epsilon) \right) \qquad \textrm{where we take any constant }\ k_A > \frac{1}{c_-} \\ & \\
B(\epsilon) &\leq \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{2\pi}{c_-\Delta^2} = \frac{4\pi^2}{c_-\Delta^2} \\ & \\
C(\epsilon) &\geq \int_{\theta^\ast(\epsilon) - \Delta}^{\theta^\ast(\epsilon) + \Delta} \frac{1}{\beta(\epsilon) + c_+(\theta-\theta^\ast(\epsilon))^2} \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\beta(\epsilon)c_+}}\mathrm{arc}\tan\left( \sqrt{\frac{c_+}{\beta(\epsilon)}} \Delta \right) \\
&\geq \frac{k_C}{\sqrt{\beta(\epsilon)}} \qquad \textrm{where we take any constant }\ 0 < k_C < \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{c_+}}.
\end{align*}
Thus, taking any constant $k_1 > \frac{k_A}{k_C}$, we have that for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$,
$$ |\theta(\epsilon)-\theta^\ast(\epsilon)| \leq -k_1\sqrt{\beta(\epsilon)}\log(\beta(\epsilon)), $$
and hence
\begin{align*}
\alpha(\epsilon) - \beta(\epsilon) &= f(\theta(\epsilon),\epsilon) - \beta(\epsilon) \\
&\leq c_+(\theta(\epsilon)-\theta^\ast(\epsilon))^2 \\
&\leq c_+\Big(\! -k_1\sqrt{\beta(\epsilon)}\log(\beta(\epsilon))\Big)^{\!2} \\
&\leq k\beta(\epsilon)[\log(\beta(\epsilon))]^2
\end{align*}
where we take any constant $k>c_+k_1^2$.

---

**Justifying points 1 and 2.**

*Proof of point 1.* We have that $\partial_\theta f(\theta^\ast,0)=0$ and $\partial_{\theta\theta}^2 f(\theta^\ast,0)>0$. Hence, by the $C^1$-robustness of zeros with invertible derivative applied to the function $\partial_\theta f$ at the point $(\theta^\ast,0)$, we have that there exist $\epsilon_1>0$ and $\Delta_1>0$ such that for all $\epsilon \in [0,\epsilon_1)$, there exists a unique number $\theta^\ast(\epsilon) \in (\theta^\ast-\Delta_1,\theta^\ast+\Delta_1)$ such that $\partial_\theta f(\theta^\ast(\epsilon),\epsilon)=0$, and furthermore $\theta^\ast(\epsilon)$ depends continuously on $\epsilon$ in the range $[0,\epsilon_1)$. [In fact, the dependence is differentiable, by the Implicit Function Theorem.] So in particular, $\theta^\ast(\epsilon) \to \theta^\ast$ as $\epsilon \to 0+$. Since $\partial_{\theta\theta}^2 f(\theta^\ast,0)>0$, it follows that for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, $\partial_{\theta\theta}^2 f(\theta^\ast(\epsilon),\epsilon)>0$. Therefore, for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, $\theta^\ast(\epsilon)$ is the unique minimiser of $f(\,\cdot\, , \epsilon)$ in $(\theta^\ast-\Delta_1,\theta^\ast+\Delta_1)$. Now taking any constant
$$ 0 < M < \min_{\theta \in [-2\pi,2\pi] \setminus (\theta^\ast-\Delta_1,\theta^\ast+\Delta_1)} f(\theta,0), $$
the continuity of $f$ together with the compactness of $[-2\pi,2\pi] \setminus (\theta^\ast-\Delta_1,\theta^\ast+\Delta_1)$ gives that for all sufficiently small $\epsilon$,
$$ M < \min_{\theta \in [-2\pi,2\pi] \setminus (\theta^\ast-\Delta_1,\theta^\ast+\Delta_1)} f(\theta,\epsilon). $$
Since $f(\theta^\ast,0)=0$, we also have by continuity of $f$ that for all sufficiently small $\epsilon$,
$$ M > f(\theta^\ast(\epsilon),\epsilon). $$
Thus, every sufficiently small $\epsilon$ has
$$ f(\theta^\ast(\epsilon),\epsilon) < \min_{\theta \in [-2\pi,2\pi] \setminus (\theta^\ast-\Delta_1,\theta^\ast+\Delta_1)} f(\theta,\epsilon), $$
and combining this with the fact that $\theta^\ast(\epsilon)$ is the unique minimiser of $f(\,\cdot\, , \epsilon)$ in $(\theta^\ast-\Delta_1,\theta^\ast+\Delta_1)$ gives that $\theta^\ast(\epsilon)$ is the unique minimiser of $f(\,\cdot\, , \epsilon)$ on the whole circle.

*Proof of point 2.* Fix any constants $c_-,c_+$ with
$$ 0 < c_- < \tfrac{1}{2}\partial_{\theta\theta}^2 f(\theta^\ast,0) < c_+. $$
Since $\partial_{\theta\theta}^2 f$ is continuous, we can find $\Delta_2 \in (0,\Delta_1]$ be such that for sufficiently small $\epsilon$,
$$ c_- < \tfrac{1}{2}\partial_{\theta\theta}^2 f(\theta,\epsilon) < c_+ \quad \forall \, \theta \in [\theta^\ast-\Delta_2,\theta^\ast+\Delta_2]. $$
Since $\theta^\ast \neq 0$ by assumption, we can assume without loss of generality that $\Delta_2$ is sufficiently small that
$$ 0 < \theta^\ast-\Delta_2 < \theta^\ast+\Delta_2 < 2\pi. $$
Taking any $\Delta_3 \in (0,\Delta_2)$, the fact that $\theta^\ast(\epsilon) \to \theta^\ast$ as $\epsilon \to 0+$ implies that for sufficiently small $\epsilon$,
$$ (\theta^\ast(\epsilon)-\Delta_3,\theta^\ast(\epsilon)+\Delta_3) \subset (\theta^\ast-\Delta_2,\theta^\ast+\Delta_2). $$
So then, since $f(\theta^\ast(\epsilon),\epsilon) = \beta(\epsilon)$ and $\partial_\theta f(\theta^\ast(\epsilon),\epsilon)=0$, we have
\begin{align*} \beta(\epsilon) + c_-(\theta-\theta^\ast(\epsilon))^2 \leq f(\theta,\epsilon) &\leq \beta(\epsilon) + c_+(\theta-\theta^\ast(\epsilon))^2 \\ & \forall \, \theta \in (\theta^\ast(\epsilon)-\Delta_3,\theta^\ast(\epsilon)+\Delta_3) \end{align*}
provided $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small. Now take any $\Delta \in (0,\Delta_3]$ such that
$$ c_-\Delta^2 < \min_{\theta \in [0,2\pi] \setminus (\theta^\ast-\Delta_2,\theta^\ast+\Delta_2)} f(\theta,0). $$
Then for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, we will have that for every $\theta \in [0,2\pi) \setminus \big[\theta^\ast(\epsilon) - \Delta,\theta^\ast(\epsilon) + \Delta\big]$,
$$ f(\theta,\epsilon) > \beta(\epsilon) + c_-\Delta^2. $$

Comment: @MathLearner Incidentally, by the Implicit Function Theorem, a generic $f$ fulfilling your requirements will have that the right-derivative of $\beta(\cdot)$ at $0$ is strictly positive. I wouldn't be surprised if, under this genericity assumption, the rate of convergence can be improved beyond what I gave. (My vague idea is to control the difference between $c_-$ and $c_+$ as $\Delta \to 0$, and combine this with the symmetry of $\big(\theta-\theta^\ast(\epsilon)\big)^{\!2}$ about $\theta^\ast(\epsilon)$ to improve the "$A(\epsilon)$" bound for some $\epsilon$-dependent choice of $\Delta$.)

Comment: I don't see why your points 1 and 2 hold (rather, I think they do not).

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you, I've now added a step-by-step justification for points 1 and 2. Let me know if you think there are any errors in this.

Comment: The OP does not say that $f(\theta, \epsilon)>0$ for $\epsilon=0$. Also, the OP does not say anything on the behavior of $f(\theta, \epsilon)$ as $\epsilon\downarrow0$. Without such conditions (that you seem to use here), it should be pretty clear that the desired conclusion will not hold in general).

Comment: $h(\theta)>0$ implies that $f(\theta, 0)>0$ for $\theta \neq \theta^*$. It's fine to assume that $f(\theta, \epsilon)$ is smooth all the way to the boundary where $\epsilon=0$. I will revise the question to state this.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I don't see any gaps in the argument under the stated assumptions now. Do you?

Comment: @MathLearner : Now this is a different story. :-)

Comment: @IosifPinelis I probably read too quickly and perhaps read both "for all $\epsilon>0$" in the first sentence as modifying $f(\theta,\epsilon)>0$. Alternatively, I may have read the first "for all $\epsilon>0$" correctly as modifying the smoothness statement, but subconsciously read it as "for all $\epsilon \geq 0$". Basically, in either case: It's so immediately obvious that you can't possibly say anything whatsoever without specifying something about $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ that I automatically read the smoothness as being simply that $f$ is smooth everywhere in its domain of definition.

Comment: Than you Julian, this is a great solution:)